# PHP: Do things depending on the time range for 2nd Thursday of the month

Tags: php, date, time

I have a quick and hopefully easy question to answer.

How do I build the following logic in PHP:

- If today's date and time is *before* the 2nd Thursday of this month at 6pm, find that date and set it in a string,
- If today's date and time is between the 2nd Thursday of this month at 6pm and 6:30pm, display a message "meeting is happening now",
- If today's date is *after* the 2nd Thursday of this month at 6:30pm, find the date for the 2nd Thursday of *next* month at 6pm, and set that in a string.

For instance:

```
if (date < 2ndThursofThisMonth_At6pm {  
    $meeting="Apr 9, 2020 18:00:00";
}
if (date > 2ndThursofThisMonth_At6pm {  
    echo "meeting happening now";
}
if (date > 2ndThursofThisMonth_At6:30pm {   
    $meeting="May 14, 2020 18:00:00";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)'s date parsing capability to find the timestamp of the meeting time, then compare the current timestamp (returned from [`time()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time)) to it to determine whether the meeting is in the future, now, or in the past (in which case we need to find the next meeting time):

```
$second_thursday = strtotime('second thursday of this month 6pm');
$now = time();
if ($now < $second_thursday) {
    $meeting = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $second_thursday);
}
elseif ($now <= $second_thursday + 1800) {
    $meeting = 'meeting happening now';
}
else {
    $meeting = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('second thursday of next month 6pm'));
}
echo $meeting;
```

Output (as of 2020-03-04):

```
2020-04-09 18:00:00
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BnEsE)

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.